# Laravel Belongs to trying to get property of Non object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I am trying to use BelongsTo to display customer details, here is my current code:

my controller:

```
$assignees = assignee::latest()
                                ->whereNull('timeout')
                                ->paginate(10);

         return view('assignees.index',compact('assignees'))
             ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
```

Assign table:

```
$table->string('original_filename')->nullable();
$table->string('custidno')->nullable();
$table->foreign('custidno')->references('custid')->on('customers');
$table->string('cardno')->nullable();
```

Customer table:

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('custid')->index()->unique();
```

Assign Model:

```
public function cust()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer','custid');
}
```

in my view: I have got the following for loop which displays the "Assignee table" I want to replace the custidno field with the customer name, taken from Customer table.

index.blade.php:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ $assignee->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $assignee->datacenter }}</td>
    <td>{{ $assignee->cust->name}}</td>
    <td>{{ $assignee->refnumber }}</td>
```

I am getting the following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Try {{ $assignee->cust()->name }}

Comment: can i see your find query ?

Comment: you must specify "with" in your query

Comment: probably your `cust ` property return null...! did  you check it?

Comment: @KaushikMakwana, I have included a snippet from my controller.

Comment: @SoheilRahmat, it shouldn't, there is an ID number in assignee->custidno.

Comment: <td>{{ isset($assignee->cust->name) ? $assignee->cust->name : '' }}</td>

Comment: `dd($assignees)` is this array or collection?

Comment: try $assignees = assignee::latest()
                                ->whereNull('timeout')
                                ->paginate(10)->cust;

Comment: please share your inverse relationship. in customer model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Assign` Model :

```
public function cust()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer','custid');
}
```

You are using `custid` which is inside `customers` table. You need to specify `custidno` which is the foreign key referencing `custid` in `customers` table.

Update it to :

```
public function cust()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer','custidno', 'custid');
}
```

That should give you correct records if exist. Then you can check further logic if data is not null then access its property.

Comment: many thanks for clearing that up!
 it is returning the customer full name now :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a fair chance that your query is returning null in it (No records).
Now when you try to access its contents (which are nothing), you get error saying **Trying to get property of non-object**

Its better to print your output you are getting from your model query and then in your code, check if there are any record before processing them. like below:

```
if( count($assignee->cust) ){ // case there are some records against this assignee
    {{ $assignee->cust->name}}
}
```

even better approach to debug this to do the following to see the output first in controller.

```
echo '<pre>'; // to proper display your output
print_r($assignee); // your object with everything in it
exit; // exit application to see your variable output
```

simply these line will help you debug your issue wherever possible.

Hope it helps :)
Best of luck

Comment: You are correct, it is returning null, I am unsure why though. I have followed all the tutorials in identifying the foreign key in the Assignee table.

Comment: @Abdul are yu getting NULL in assignee table or from customer model relationship?
try to fetch records without paginating them for understanding

Comment: for this line
<td>{{ $assignee->cust->name}}</td>
there is a chance that an assignee customer id is null so when we try to access belonging customer name, error occurs

Comment: you might need to update your relationship foreign key to not null in order to make sure there is a record against an assignee